# CLI-based Disk Speed Checking Utility for Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, ssd

I'm looking for a tool that can check SSD speed from the CLI on Ubuntu 20.04. I've already checked out kdiskmark but it won't run without a GUI.

Comment: Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108838/how-can-i-benchmark-my-hdd